# Поместить в таблицу элемент с незанятым id

Tags: mysql, sql

Мне нужно добавить элемент с незанятым id. Я не особо силён в MySQL, но нашел какой-то код.

Вот код который у меня был:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `test` (id) VALUES (
  (SELECT (`test`.`id`+1) AS `empty_id`
  FROM `players`
  WHERE (
      SELECT 1 FROM `test` AS `st` WHERE `st`.`id` = (`test`.`id` + 1)
  ) IS NULL
  LIMIT 1)
);
```

При попытке добавить элемент, если в таблице ничего нет - ничего не получается.

Comment: просто добавляй без явного указания id и всё. значение автоматически запишется в свободную ячейку

Comment: @DrMcSheen Можешь код как пример дать?

Comment: INSERT INTO `твоя таблица` (столбец1, столбец5) VALUES (значение_для_столбец1, значение_для_столбец5)